# Changing table schema at run-time in Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework

What is the best way to change database table schema at run time in Play! Framework? I get an unspecified amount of columns from a client application and can not have domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Apache DDLUtils ?
It's not plugged by default in Play! but I use it in other projects and it's quite useful.
http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to use a schema-less datastore ala mongodb.  Seems like there is a mongo module for play, http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo.

Comment: You are quite right. But I have to use PostgreSQL because of its current deployment and integration with various other GIS apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you were looking for

have a look at play [snippets](http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets)

http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/13

public class Application extends Controller {

```
@Before
public static void setDBSchema() {
    String schema = "someSchema"; // This can come from a Cache, for example

    Play.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", schema);

    JPA.entityManagerFactory = null;
    JPAPlugin plugin = new JPAPlugin();
    plugin.onApplicationStart();
}

...
```

you just change the configured hibernate schema, and then force the JPAPlugin to restart